# How to create a scale-break on the y-axis in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, information-graphics, chart-design

I would like to create a chart in Illustrator (not yet sure if it will be an area chart or a stacked column chart), but need to "skip" some values (as in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196138/what-to-call-the-symbol-where-there-is-a-break-in-content-or-a-break-in-a-graph) on English StackExchange, which queries what to even call such a thing).

Ideally, I would like to do it with the graph tool, so that changes are easier if I need to update the data later, but I understand that Illustrator's graph tool is rather limited, so if I must use another method, so be it.

If this is a well-known design problem where I've simply failed at proper Googling, and/or the answer is overly complex, I'll happily take a pointer to a YouTube video.

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this. Time to learn scripting. Or moce to a proper tool like say mathematica.